# Преобразование типов MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите почему

```
SELECT CAST(12 AS CHAR) +'12';//24
SELECT CAST(12 AS CHAR) +cast('12' AS CHAR)";//24
```

Как преобразовать к строке??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 1):

24 получается потому что Mysql при использовании оператора + автоматически приводит операнды в числа. А если нужно сложить именно 2 строки, то да нужно использовать CONCAT().